# Generic AsyncTask approach interferes with UI thread

Tags: java, android, user-interface, concurrency, android-asynctask

in the progress of building a concurrent HTTP service in my Android application I came across a nice way to handle the results generated by AsyncTask using an interface to register the UI-activity as a listener:

```
public interface Activity {
   void callback(String result);
}
```

AsyncTask class:

```
public class HTTP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Activity activity;

    public HTTP(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://" + params[0] + ":" + params[1] + "/" + params[2]);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            http.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.connect();

            ...

            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        activity.callback(result);
    }
}
```

The actual activity:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Activity {

    public void callback(String result) {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            toast(result);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

    Button mCreateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_button);
    assert mCreateButton != null;
    mCreateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            host = mHostEditText.getText().toString();
            port = mPortEditText.getText().toString();
            data = mDataEditText.getText().toString();

            if (host.isEmpty() || port.isEmpty() || data.isEmpty()) {
                toast(ERR_EMPTY_FIELDS);
            } else {
                new HTTP(CreateActivity.this).execute(host, port, "ai", makeJson());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

According to logcat this approach still blocks the calling thread for almost 200 frames, which is a total mystery to me.
The idea derives from this repo:

https://github.com/levinotik/ReusableAsyncTask/tree/master/src/com/example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `makeJson()` take a long time?

Comment: It shouldn't. A tiny object is converted to a String using GSON from Google.

Answer (score 0):

So after performing some benchmarks I came to the conclusion that the hanging thread is caused by the cryptographic setup inside of `makeJson()`.

AsyncTask should therefore be fine.

Comment: You could move makeJson() into the AsyncTask if you pass the small object itself to it instead of the json representation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the only matter that can consume lot of time on UI thread in your code is makeJson() method.

But You should not hold strong reference to Activity inside your AsyncTask, when Activity is recreated (or destroyed) your AsyncTask could be still running and holding reference to "dead" Activity. Simples solution is cancel your AsyncTask when Activity is destroying.